# VBA loops not summing values correctly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a script that generates a number of combinations from a variable number of variables (up to 15).

What I have noticed is that in certain instances not all combinations of the variables are generated.

For instance, the below image of inputs with the below script has the following output which is not correct as it misses the combination 0%/100% and 10%/90%.

Similarly, the second image of variables misses the 50%/50% combination.

In both instances, when I step through the iterations, the variables come up to be correct, however the IF statement fails.

If (a2 + a3 = 1)   returns "false" when the values for a2 and a3 actually DO sum to be 1.

HELP here would be great :). I cannot figure this out. I have dimmed the variables, bracket-ised them and more.....

> output 1 corresponding to image 1:

```
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.2, 0.8
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.3, 0.7
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.5, 0.5
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.7, 0.3
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.8, 0.2

Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.2, 0.8
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.3, 0.7
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.5, 0.5
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.7, 0.3
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.8, 0.2

Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.2, 0.8
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.3, 0.7
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.5, 0.5
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.7, 0.3
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.8, 0.2
```

> output 2 corresponding to image 2

```
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.35, 0.65
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var1 - origin/destination - AT, 1000, 0.65, 0.35

Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.35, 0.65
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var2 - westbound - Road (car), 1000, 0.65, 0.35

Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.35, 0.65
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.4, 0.6
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.6, 0.4
Var3 - westbound - Road (bus), 1000, 0.65, 0.35
```

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

````
```
Sub generatorX4()

Dim genX As Worksheet
Dim corbuildX As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Dim filenameX As String
Dim a1 As Variant, a2 As Variant, a3 As Variant
Dim varX() As String, loX() As Variant, hiX() As Variant, incrementX() As Variant

Set genX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("generator")
'Set corbuildX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Corridor builder")

With genX
    filenameX = .Cells(2, 1)
End With

pathX = "C:\Users\xxxx" & filenameX & ".txt"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

lastvariable = genX.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastsegment = genX.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'>>>RESIZE ARRAYS
sizeX = lastvariable - 8
ReDim varX(sizeX)
ReDim loX(sizeX)
ReDim hiX(sizeX)
ReDim incrementX(sizeX)

'>>>ESTABLISH VARIABLES
For e = 8 To lastvariable
    With genX
        varX(e - 8) = .Cells(e, 3).Value
        loX(e - 8) = .Cells(e, 4).Value
        hiX(e - 8) = .Cells(e, 5).Value
        incrementX(e - 8) = .Cells(e, 6).Value
    End With
Next e


Open pathX For Output As #1

For i = 8 To lastsegment
Application.StatusBar = "generating " & i & " of " & lastsegment & " segments"
With genX
    segmentX = .Cells(i, 2)
End With

'For counter = 0 To sizeX


For a1 = loX(0) To hiX(0) Step incrementX(0)
If 0 = sizeX Then
If a1 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1
End If
GoTo endX1
End If
For a2 = loX(1) To hiX(1) Step incrementX(1)
If 1 = sizeX Then
If (a2 = 1) Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2
End If
GoTo endX2
End If
For a3 = loX(2) To hiX(2) Step incrementX(2)
If 2 = sizeX Then
If (a2 + a3 = 1) Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3
End If
GoTo endX3
End If
For a4 = loX(3) To hiX(3) Step incrementX(3)
If 3 = sizeX Then
If (a2 + a3 + a4 = 1) Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4
End If
GoTo endX4
End If
For a5 = loX(4) To hiX(4) Step incrementX(4)
If 4 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5
End If
GoTo endX5
End If
For a6 = loX(5) To hiX(5) Step incrementX(5)
If 5 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6
End If
GoTo endX6
End If
For a7 = loX(6) To hiX(6) Step incrementX(6)
If 6 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7
End If
GoTo endX7
End If
For a8 = loX(7) To hiX(7) Step incrementX(7)
If 7 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8
End If
GoTo endX8
End If
For a9 = loX(8) To hiX(8) Step incrementX(8)
If 8 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9
End If
GoTo endX9
End If
For a10 = loX(9) To hiX(9) Step incrementX(9)
If 9 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10
End If
GoTo endX10
End If
For a11 = loX(10) To hiX(10) Step incrementX(10)
If 10 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11
End If
GoTo endX11
End If
For a12 = loX(11) To hiX(11) Step incrementX(11)
If 11 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11 & ", " & a12
End If
GoTo endX12
End If
For a13 = loX(12) To hiX(12) Step incrementX(12)
If 12 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11 & ", " & a12 & ", " & a13
End If
GoTo endX13
End If
For a14 = loX(13) To hiX(13) Step incrementX(13)
If 13 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13 + a14 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11 & ", " & a12 & ", " & a13 & ", " & a14
End If
GoTo endX14
End If
For a15 = loX(14) To hiX(14) Step incrementX(14)
If 14 = sizeX Then
If a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13 + a14 + a15 = 1 Then
Print #1, segmentX & ", " & a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11 & ", " & a12 & ", " & a13 & ", " & a14 & ", " & a15
End If
GoTo endX15
End If

endX15:
Next a15
endX14:
Next a14
endX13:
Next a13
endX12:
Next a12
endX11:
Next a11
endX10:
Next a10
endX9:
Next a9
endX8:
Next a8
endX7:
Next a7
endX6:
Next a6
endX5:
Next a5
endX4:
Next a4
endX3:
Next a3
endX2:
Next a2
endX1:
Next a1

'Next counter

Next i

Close #1


End Sub
```

```
`
````

Comment: Looks like your `a1`, `a2` and `a3` variables are only numbers - try dim them as `long` instead of `variant`?

Comment: In fact, your variables `loX()`, `hiX()` and `incrementX()` Should also be numeric (such as `long` or `integer`) not variants

Answer (score 1):

I would try `debug.print(a2 a3)` to test the output. It could be that there is a type conflict *e.g. the output could be `1.00` instead of `1`*